# CakePHP unable to sort by date using MAX(date) and pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I need to sort some data by date, but somehow I can not manage to make it work correctly.
It is probably because I use `MAX(UserConnexion.date) as date` but I can not figure out how to solve this.

I am using this to paginate :

*Controlleur.php*

```
$this->UserConnexion->virtualFields['count'] = 'COUNT(UserConnexion.email)';
$order = "UserConnexion.count";

$paginate=array(
    'fields'=>array('COUNT(UserConnexion.email) as count, 
                     email, 
                     MAX(UserConnexion.date) as date'),
    'group'=>array('UserConnexion.email'),
    'order'=>array($order => 'DESC')
);

$this->Paginator->settings = $paginate;
```

*View.ctp*

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('date', 'Last connexion'); ?></th>
```

The output of the pagination is the following :

```
array(    
    (int) 0 => array(     
        (int) 0 => array(    
            'count' => '67',     
            'date' => '2015-05-15 10:09:43'   
        ),      
        'AgentsAppUserconnect' => array(      
            'email' => 'hugo@email.fr'     
        )   
    ),      
    (int) 1 => array(        
        (int) 0 => array(      
            'count' => '1',        
            'date' => '2015-04-27 15:27:52'      
        ),          
        'AgentsAppUserconnect' => array(        
            'email' => 'ludo@email.fr'      
        )     
    )        )
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: try `'fields'=>array('UserConnexion.count, ...`

Comment: Thanks for your answers (can I say thanks here?) but the problem is not with the count but with the max...

Comment: @hg8 did you get this solved?

Comment: No still unsolved...

Comment: @hg8 did you get this solved?

Comment: I did not. If someday I do I will post an answer.